# Assetic Dump Cannot Locate File

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, production-environment, assetic

I am currently trying to move my Symfony App from dev to prod. I am running this commandline script to compile my js and css files:

```
 php app/console assetic:dump --watch;
```

When I do so, I get the following error:

```
 The source file "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/symfonydev/app/../web/assets/js/js/bootstrap/" does not exist.
```

I have also run this script:

```
php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug
```

It gives me a whole other bunch of issues which I will put in another post question.

I have run these scripts to see I can find the file that this is happening in:

```
 find . -name '*.html.twig' -exec grep -li 'assets/js/js/bootstrap*' {} \;
 find . -name '*.html.twig' -exec grep -li 'js/js/bootstrap*' {} \;
 find . -name '*.html.twig' -exec grep -li 'js/bootstrap*' {} \;
```

They return no values :(

I cannot compile my js files because I keep getting this error. How in the world do I proceed in moving this Symfony2 app! Please assist if you could.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using MopaBootstrapBundle ?

Comment: do you have java installed on server? If you are using yuicompressor then you need java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the issue, I had some Bundles in Symfony that were incorrectly configured. Then I found a rouge directory that I made waaaaaaay back when and removed it. Once I did that and ran

```
 sudo rm -rf app/cache/* app/logs/*
```

and then ran

```
 php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug
```

all was well. Thanks for your feedback everyone!